# CheckBox html-php-mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

my problem sir/ma'am is in checkbox html-php-mysql, if box is check then the value that will save in MYSql is "COMPLETED" and if it is not check the box then it will also save the value of "NOT COMPLETED" in mysql, but in my case it will save still NOT COMPLETED even it is check

```html
 <h1><span class="label label-primary left">Requirements</span></h1><br><br>


                     <div class="checkbox ">
                         <label><input type="checkbox" name="Card" value="Complete">
                          <input type="hidden" name="Card" value="Not Complete">High School Card (Form 138)</label>
    </div> <div class="checkbox b">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="MoralCertificate" value="Complete">
           <input type="hidden" name="MoralCertificate" value="Not Complete">
            Good Moral Certificate</label>
    </div> <div class="checkbox bb">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="BirthCertificate" value="Complete">
            <input type="hidden" name="BirthCertificate" value="Not Complete">
            NSO Birth Certificate</label>
    </div> <div class="checkbox bbb">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="IDPicture" value="Complete">
            <input type="hidden" name="IDPicture" value="Not Complete">

            2x2 Formal ID Picture</label>
    </div> <div class="checkbox bbbb">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="HonorStudents" value="Complete">
            <input type="hidden" name="HonorStudents" value="Not Complete">
            Certification for Honor Students</label>
    </div> <div class="checkbox bbbbb">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Form137" value="Complete">
            <input type="hidden" name="Form137" value="Not Complete">
            Form 137</label>
    </div>    


    $Elementary = $_POST['Elementary'];
            $YearGraduated = $_POST['YearGraduated'];
            $AwardsReceived = $_POST['AwardsReceived'];
            $Year = $_POST['Year'];
            $Place = $_POST['Place'];
            $status = $_POST['Card'];
             $MoralCertificate = $_POST['MoralCertificate'];
      $BirthCertificate = $_POST['BirthCertificate']; 
              $IDPicture = $_POST['IDPicture'];
                $HonorStudents = $_POST['HonorStudents'];
                  $Form137 = $_POST['Form137'];




            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO educationalbackground (Elementary, YearGraduated, AwardsReceived, Year, Place, Card, MoralCertificate, BirthCertificate, IDPicture, HonorStudents, Form137 )
    VALUES ('$Elementary','$YearGraduated', '$AwardsReceived', '$Year', '$Place', '$status', '$MoralCertificate', '$BirthCertificate', '$IDPicture', '$HonorStudents',  '$Form137')");
 header("Location: ThirdForm.php");

            mysqli_close($con);
```

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfJGt.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qxp6.png)

Comment: look ma, no code to fix.

Comment: I think. You missed code.

Comment: sorry im new here i post the picture and i dont know where it is now

Comment: still no input where you checking "sir/ma'am" where are this tags?

Comment: Why not just have one checkbox for each field, then test the results is php like `if(isset('checkboxname')){ \\completed }else{ \\ not completed }`

Comment: my problem is even it is check, still it will record NOT RECORDED in mysql

Comment: thank you to all of you, thank you for teaching me

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify this using one checkbox per item.

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Card" value=1>
        High School Card (Form 138)
   </label>
</div>
```

Then in php check the results like so....

```
 if(isset($_POST['Card'])){
      // Card Completed
 }else{
      // Card Not Completed
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome! Checkboxes can be tricky :) Please accept my answer if you found it to solve your issue.